# How can I make this JavaScript code display the post title?

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

I am using the [Tumblr Badge script](https://code.google.com/p/tumblrbadge/) to embed my Tumblr feed on my website. Originally, there was no post title support so I added this code.

```
postTitle = document.createElement("h3");
postTitle.className = "tumblr-post-title";
postTitle.innerHTML = post["regular-title"];
listItem.appendChild(postTitle);
```

This will display the post title, but on posts without titles it displays "undefined" instead. Is there some way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: You could try `postTitle.innerHTML = post["regular-title"] || "";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "regular-title" isn't a property of `post`, it will return `undefined`. An easy, quick fix is to return an empty string if so:

```
postTitle.innerHTML = post["regular-title"] || "";
```

This will check to see if `post["regular-title"]` is a truthy value (**not** any of these: `false`, `0`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `""`, `null`). If it's truthy, it will set the `innerHTML` with `post["regular-title"]`...otherwise with the `""`.